# Область видимости JS, не выводит на страницу информацию

Tags: javascript, if, for, область-видимости

доброе времени суток, вопрос следующий
У нас есть вверстка с инпутом где при вводе цифры ( будет дописано дальше больше значений) пока к примеру 15, данные с двух масивов заполняют наш объект my, путем перебора, на выходе, если в данном скрипте ввести в инпут 15, в console.log получаем следующее
12 - кількість 2
15 - кількість 3
19 - кількість 4

логика работает, вопрос только в том, как выводить такие данные не в console.log а напрямую на страничку, добавлением div или innerHTML, пробывал много способов, выводит только первое значение -12 - кількість 2 и дальше не выводит, буду благодарен в подсказке

```
//HTML
<input type='text' id='main'>
<div id="container"></div>


//JS
let userData = document.getElementById("main");
let containerData = document.getElementById("container");

userData.addEventListener("mouseout", run);



function run() {
  my = {};
  let dataValue = userData.value;
  let percent = ['2', '3', '4'];
  let Num = ['12', '15', '19'];
  if (my) {
    if (dataValue == 15) {
      for (let i = 0; i < percent.length; i++) {
        my[`${percent[i]}`] = `${Num[i]} - кількість`;
      }
      for (let i in my) {
        console.log(`${my[i]} ${i}`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('введіть коректну цифру - 15,19,22,25');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `containerData.innerHTML += str;`?

Comment: Действительно, сработало ) 
спасибо большое, все оказалось проще чем я пробывал и думал ))